# I'm tryin to use Sharedpreferences to save an arraylist of objects, but toJson and fromJson are causing fatal exceptions

Tags: android, json, gson, sharedpreferences

My object contains a String, long, and int.  Object is called Tracker and I have an arrayList of Trackers.  When I try to use toJson i get an error.  The same with fromJson.  I get this everytime.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.unknownuser.scrapstable, PID: 13550
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.unknownuser.scrapstable/com.example.unknownuser.scrapstable.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class android.content.res.ColorStateList declares multiple JSON fields named mChangingConfigurations
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class android.content.res.ColorStateList declares multiple JSON fields named mChangingConfigurations
     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:170)
     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
     at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:115)
     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:164)
     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
     at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:115)
     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:164)
     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
     at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:115)
     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:164)
     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
     at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:115)
     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:164)
     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
     at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.create(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:53)
     at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887)
     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:853)
     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:802)
     at com.example.unknownuser.scrapstable.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:109)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
```

I have activity A that tries to save the ArrayList of Trackers:

```
Tracker trax = new Tracker(description, timeToCount, imageID);
track.add(trax);

sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = sharedPref.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(track);
editor.putString("LeftoverList", json);
editor.commit();
```

In Activity B, I try to retrieve the ArrayList of Trackers

```
ArrayList<Tracker> foodList;

sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
gson = new Gson();
json = sharedPref.getString("LeftoverList", " ");

type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Tracker>>(){}.getType();
foodList = gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

The lines using the methods `toJson` and `fromJson` are giving me the fatal exceptions.  Thanks so much for whoever helps.

Comment: `multiple JSON fields named mChangingConfigurations`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to convert a list to json as an object instead of a list. You could just create a wrapper class to hold your list and serialize/deserialize *that*.

Create a simple class that acts as a wrapper for your List.

```
class TrackWrapper {
    List<Tracker> trackList;

    public TrackWrapper(List<Tracker> tracks){
        this.trackList = tracks;
    }
}
```

Add items to the list

```
Tracker trax = new Tracker(description, timeToCount, imageID);
track.add(trax);
```

Create an instance of your wrapper class and pass your list in

```
TrackWrapper wrapper = new TrackWrapper(trax);
```

Serialise the wrapper

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(wrapper);
```

Comment: Would it be alright if you showed me an example of this wrapper class ?

Comment: Edited my answer to provide an example.

Comment: Thanks so much everyone.  I figured out what was wrong.  My Tracker class had unused variables that I forgot to comment out.  One of them was another class object which was not being serialized properly.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at my [SharedPreferences helper](https://github.com/kingfisherphuoc/EasySharedPreference)

```
// Save list object to another SharedPreference
SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance(AnotherPreferenceName).putValue("guns", guns);
List<Gun> datas = SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance(AnotherPreferenceName).getValues("guns", Gun[].class); // get list object
```